# Add a not exist element from String to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I'm reading from a txt file. The file is something like this, separate with a tab `"/t"`

```
 ID    name    test    date    object
 1     John    pass    9/13    RC_CUST_1
 2     John    fail    10/13   RC_CUST_1
 3     John    pass
```

I'm reading the txt file like this:

```
String line="";
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
FileReader fIn;
BufferedReader buff;

fIn = new FileReader("...");
buff = new BufferedReader( fIn );

while( ( line = buff.readLine() ) != null  )
{
        if(!line.isEmpty())
            data.add(line);
}
```

In late of my code I do that:

```
    ArrayList<String> name1  = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> RC1  = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> date1  = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> pass1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String [] substr2;

for(int k=0;k<data.size();k++)
{
    substr2=data.get(k).split("\t");
    RC1.add(substr2[4]);
    name1.add(substr2[1]);
    date1.add(substr2[3]);
    pass1.add(substr2[2]);      
}
```

And I have an error because you can see, my ID number 3 has not any date or object. How can I fix that, and how can I know what ID has not a `date` or an `object`

I would like for example to print: `ID number x has not date` or `ID number x has not any object` if I have a error of this type

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Comment: Your tab delimited seems to be malformed, because an empty field not should mean that any tabs are actually missing.  The best solution is to go back to your data source and fix it there.

Comment: Isn't it quite error prone to split by `"\t"`? I would use an arbitrary amount of whitespaces instead: `.split("\\s+");`... Consider creating a class representing a person or a test (depends) representing your data, a bunch of `ArrayList`s might get hard to handle later on. Also consider using `java.nio` to access file content, you can simply stream the lines by `java.nio.file.Files.lines(java.nio.file.Path filePath);`.

Comment: The error it's not about `"\t"`. I get the error only if a field it's empty. I mean the error is when there when I try to add the `substr2[x]` in `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the split on `\t` you get an array as result. you can check the length of the array before accessing the fields in it.

```
for(int k=0;k<data.size();k++) {
    String [] substr2 = data.get(k).split("\t");
    int length = substr2.length
    if (length >= 5) {
        RC1.add(substr2[4]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("no object found");
    }
    ....     
}
```